# Mess of Potage, the RED, EDOM

Tags: blessing

I'm interested in the emphasis given to the etymology of the references to 'RED' - the colour of the lentils Jacob was cooking, then transferring the description to Esau as EDOM, the red man.
It seems to me that this already shows the break between a transhumant, herd pasturing cohort and the realisation that settlement/farming had a value - else Jacob would not have lentils, not wheat nor anything else the people of the Land cultivated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a statement not a question

Comment: @sabbahillel May be that it is a statement but may bee that the OP is a request of confirmation. That is "I have an intuition, I guess that I pointed an allusion (a remez) in the verse, please give me a confirmation in Hazal/Show me where sages refer to this clue".

Comment: Alin welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for your first question! It was a bit unclear so got closed. If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). This might help you better understand how MY works. Or you could read something I wrote to help you understand the site ["A beginner’s guide to MY - How is this site different from other Judaism sites”](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501)
 ? In all cases I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest and stay learning with us.

Comment: Also please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

Answer (score 2):

It says that Jacob was cooking the lentils, then Esau came along hungry.

Jewish tradition has it that round foods are served for mourners to represent the circle of life (today hard-boiled eggs are used), and the chronology has this story at the time of Abraham's death. Thus Jacob is cooking lentils to give his father Isaac, who just lost his father.

The simplest explanation on the "red" thing is that Esau is so animalistic, he can't use his faculty of speech to identify the food before him, other than by its color. "HUNGRY. FEED ME. RED STUFF."

Abraham had already been serving guests wheatcakes, so eating cultivated plants was nothing new by this point.